# Max and min in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, min

I have the a collection of entries as follows:

```
{
  company:"C3",
  model:"M3",
  price:55600,
  discount:9,
  ...
}
```

and there are more than 2000 entries.

I am trying to find out `max` **and** `min` prices in the whole collection.

Maybe with something along the lines of:

```
db.collection.find({ max: { $max: "$price" }, min: { $min: "$price" } });
```

I'd like the output as `{ max: 2000, min: 5000 }`.

Comment: what did u mean by *it didn't work* did you get any error message?

Comment: oh i see , i was not using _id as null , it is showing the expected result thanks ..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to use the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method for it to work.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "max": { "$max": "$price" }, 
        "min": { "$min": "$price" } 
    }}
])
```

The `_id` field is mandatory in the [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage and to find the [`max`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max)/[`min`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#grp._S_min) values for price for the whole collection not for special group it needs to be set to *null* otherwise the query will return multiple max/min results, a result for each group

Comment: For very large collections aggregating pipeline can be very slow because it scans each document.
The solution mentioned here can be better if you need to find min/max of the indexed field: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6360583/3438640
Use find with sort and limit: `db.collection.find().sort({price: 1}).limit(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of a [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage, combined with `$sort`/`$limit` stages:

```
// { "price": 123 }
// { "price": 165 }
// { "price": 98  }
// { "price": 34  }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $facet: {
    min: [{ $sort: { price:  1 } }, { $limit: 1 }],
    max: [{ $sort: { price: -1 } }, { $limit: 1 }]
  }},
  { $project: { min: { $first: "$min.price" }, max: { $first: "$max.price" } } }
])
// { "min" : 34, "max" : 165 }
```

The `$facet` stage allows us to run multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents. Each sub-pipeline has its own field in the output document where its result is stored as an array of documents.

Each field is thus produced by its own aggregation pipeline whose first stage `$sort`s prices in a specified order, followed by a `$limit` stage that'll only keep the first item (the smallest as defined by the chosen ordering).

The second part of the pipeline (the [`$project`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) / [`$first`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) stage) is just there to clean-up the `$facet` output to the format you wished for.

---

Note that a `$sort` followed by a `$limit` stage is optimised by Mongo (see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-sort----limit-coalescence)). This allows the sort operation to only maintain the top n results (in our case only 1 element) as it progresses.

Also note that our `$sort` stages will benefit from having an index on `price`.

---

For older versions of MongoDB, `$first` may not be available yet, in which case you can use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) instead.