# Which is the best way to find min and max in same Mongodb query

Tags: java, mongodb

sorry to bother you, but I am not able to find a working solution to my question. I want to make a MongoDB query that give me the same results from an SQL query:
 `SELECT MIN(ZIP) AS MIN, MAX(ZIP) AS MAX FROM table WHERE BUSINESS_STATE_TERRITORY='Arizona'`
First of all I'm querying the database from java using the mongodb java driver 3.6version. 
I tried this solution from [How to find min value in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360465/how-to-find-min-value-in-mongodb)

```
db.sales.aggregate(
[
  {
    $group:
    {
      _id: "$item",
      minQuantity: { $min: "$quantity" }
    }
  }
]
)
```

In java:

```
Document min = new Document("$min","$ZIP");
Document max = new Document("$max","$ZIP");
Document group = new Document("$group", new Document("_id","$Business_State_Territory").append("minimum",min).append("maximum",max));
Document match = new Document("$match", new Document("Business_State_Territory","Arizona"));
AggregateIterable output = coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match,group));
MongoCursor<Document> cur = output.iterator();
    while(cur.hasNext()){
        Document next = cur.next();
        System.out.println(next.toString());
    }
```

the result is:

```
Document{{_id=Arizona, minimum=1608, maximum=null}}
```

But it isn't evaluating the max value, that is 99701.

All the documents in the collections follow this structure:

```
_id:5ad0aea8471aa1aa7f425885
NPI:1003000142
CCN:""
Provider_Type:"EP"
Business_State_Territory:"Ohio"
ZIP:43623
Specialty:"Pain Medicine"
Hospital_Type:""
Program_Type:"Medicare"
Program_Year:2016
Provider_Stage_Number:"Stage 2"
Payment_Year:3
Attestation_Month:2
Attestation_Year:2017
MU_Definition_2014:""
Stage_2_Scheduled_2014:0
EHR_Certification_Number:"1314E01QPVPIEAN"
EHR_Product_CHP_Id:"CHP-027887"
Vendor_Name:"Epic Systems Corporation"
EHR_Product_Name:"EpicCare Ambulatory 2014 Certified EHR Suite"
EHR_Product_Version:"Epic 2015"
Product_Classification:"Complete EHR"
Product_Setting:"Ambulatory"
Product_Certification_Edition_Yr:2014
```

I hope you can help me out.
Start editing:
I tried to use $project instead of $group with only the max clause. Now the result documents are in a structure of:

```
Document{{_id=5ad0aea8471aa1aa7f425955, Business_State_Territory=Arizona, maximum=85255}}
```

As you can see now the maximum value is not empty but the values are not representing the maximum value. The odd thing is also that some documents are:

```
Document{{_id=5ad0aea9471aa1aa7f426881, Business_State_Territory=Arizona, maximum=}}
```

Can it be that mongodb interprets this empty value as tha maximum value? From docs.mongodb.com it says: *If some, but not all, documents for the $max operation have either a null value for the field or are missing the field, the $max operator only considers the non-null and the non-missing values for the field.* So the answer must be no, the empty value is not taken for the result of the query. Is this a bug?

Comment: Hi RolloBallo - could  you paste in an example of your data? It would help us understand precisely how to query it correctly.

Comment: Added the document structure as you said

Comment: With the corrections to the field name, and the leading $, it looks like your query should be able to get both min and max now. If max still isn't working, could you try removing the min part and see if it can get just the max by itself?

Comment: it returns me this: Document{{_id=Arizona, maximum=}}

Comment: That is very odd; I can't think of a reason why $min would work but not $max. I hope this isn't condescending, but could you double-check the spelling and capitalisation of the field name `"$ZIP"` again?

Comment: I have tried with ZIP, Zip, zip. With Zip and zip it returns null. With all uppercases Document{{_id=Arizona, maximum=}}.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it the right way, using an aggregation. You don't need to do mapReduce. You need to make a correction though:

When you use the $group operator, you need to refer to any document fields with a leading **$**, like in the example:

```
{ $group: {_id: "$item", minQuantity: { $min: "$quantity" } }
```

In your example, try adding the leading $ to the field name `Business_State_Territory`, like this:

```
Document group = new Document("$group", new Document("_id","$Business_State_Territory").append("minimum",min).append("maximum",max));
```

Comment: Thanks to answer me. I tried right now but same result as before: Document{{_id=Arizona, minimum=null, maximum=null}}