# How to find user with lowest - loginattempts value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
[{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 6, createdAt:2018-11-30 20:49:52.855},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 1, createdAt:2018-11-30 20:49:52.855},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 8, createdAt:2018-11-30 20:49:52.855},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 5, createdAt:2018-11-30 20:49:52.855},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 5, createdAt:2018-11-30 20:49:52.855},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 5, createdAt:2018-11-30 20:49:52.855},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 3, createdAt:2018-11-30 20:49:52.855}]
```

Above is a snapshot of User Document. How can I find a user with least loginAttempts value. If same value is found for mutliple users then return one having creationDate value.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360465/how-to-find-min-value-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the "sort and limit" technique.

`db.users.find().sort({ loginAttempts: 1 }).limit(1)`

Comment: Hopefully it's logical how to extend this technique to apply more criteria such as your creationDate requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you're querying the model you can use `sort` or `order by`.

```
db.col.find({category: A}).sort({loginAttempts: 1, createdAt: -1}).limit(1)
```

In follows the left to right order while sorting.

Or you can just loop through the array,

```
result.sort((a,b) => {
      return (a.loginAttempts - b.loginAttempts) || (b.createdAt - a.createdAt);
})[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce and some ternary operators

```js
var data = [{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 6, createdAt:"2018-11-30 20:49:52.855"},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 1, createdAt:"2018-11-30 20:49:52.855"},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 1, createdAt:"2018-11-11 20:49:52.855"},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 5, createdAt:"2018-11-30 20:49:52.855"},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 5, createdAt:"2018-11-30 20:49:52.855"},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 5, createdAt:"2018-11-30 20:49:52.855"},
{"_id":"5c0155a8407cf173d7ff01fa",loginAttempts : 3, createdAt:"2018-11-30 20:49:52.855"}]

smallest = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.loginAttempts < curr.loginAttempts ? prev : curr.loginAttempts == prev.loginAttempts ? new Date(prev.createdAt) < new Date(curr.createdAt) ? prev : curr : curr;
});
console.log(smallest);
```