# mongodb query with minimum as a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb

I have many users. Some may have the same 'top' (type of problem) and the timestamp will naturally be unique. I am trying to find users/documents with a specific top (i.e "top":1) but amongst those, I only want the one with the smallest/minimum timestamp.

```
db.collection.find( {'top':1} ).min("timestamp")
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find min value in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360465/how-to-find-min-value-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

`.find(...).next()` is the solution