# How to find the min value of a specific field in MongoDB using C# driver 2.10.4

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi i am new in mongoDB and in C#. I want to find the min value of a specific filed from my collection.

I have created the following class

```
     public class GlobalUrbanPoint
        {
            [BsonId]
            public ObjectId  Id{ get; set; }
            public double LATITUDE { get; set; }
            public double LONGITUDE { get; set; }
            ...
        }
```

For the operation I have following function for the connection and other.

```
     public class MongoCRUD
        {
            private IMongoDatabase db;

            public MongoCRUD(string database)
            {
                var client = new MongoClient();
                db = client.GetDatabase(database);
            }
            ...
            public void NormalizeCoordinates<T>(string table)
            {
                var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
                // something is wrong the selection  
                var result = collection.AsQueryable<T>().Select(LATITUDE => LATITUDE).Min<T>();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
```

This is the `Main` function:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using MongoDB.Bson;
    using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MongoCRUD db = new MongoCRUD("testClass");

            var newTable = "points";

            /* find The min value*/
            db.NormalizeCoordinates<GlobalUrbanPoint>(newTable);
         }
```

If I run this I get an exception : `System.NotSupportedException: '$project or $group does not support {document}.'`

I have try and a different approach that i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360465/how-to-find-min-value-in-mongodb) with the use of FindAs().

```
    var cursor =  collection.FindAs<T>(Query.And()).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending(fieldName)).SetLimit(1).SetFields(fieldName);
```

Again, I have the same luck.

Can someone explain me how to get the min value properly from my collection.
Thank you, for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're returning from MongoDB's query/aggregation needs to be an object and if you want to get min/max values from entire collection you need to [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-null) that collection by a constant value:

```
var q = collection.Aggregate()
                  .Group(
                      x => 1,
                      gr => new {MinVal = gr.Min(f => f.LONGITUDE)});

var result = q.First().MinVal;
```

Comment: thank for the quick response. I have a question in f.LONGITUDE i get an error that 'T' does not contain a definition for 'LONGITUDE' and no accessible extension method 'LONGITUDE' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I need to specified the class 'T' ???

Comment: @GiannisAggelis ah, your code is generic so you need to use `where T: Interface` and that inteface should have `LONGITUDE` property so that compiler knows that prop and then your  `GlobalUrbanPoint` should implement that interface